# Push an object into an existing object

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I have an existing object and I want to push a new object into it with no property to target

So for instance:

```
  existingObj = { data: {postion: 1 } };
  objToPush = { person: [{ name: "Bella", age: 100}], about: { height: "1.70", weight: "170"} }

  end up with existingObj = { data: {postion: 1 }, person: [{ name: "Bella", age: 100}], about: { height: "1.70", weight: "170"} }
```

So I want to add `objTopush` into `existingObj`, but there is no property to target in `existingObj`

Comment: `let newObj = Object.assign({}, existingObj, objToPush);` [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Can I use the spread operator ?

Comment: If that makes you feel good.

Comment: Are you wanting to mutate the original?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes

Comment: In that case just do `Object.assign(existingObj, objToPush)` and properties from objToPush will be added to existingObj. The version above as well as existing answer both create new objects

Answer (score 5):

You can use spread syntax.

```js
const existingObj = { data: { postion: 1 } };
const objToPush = {
  person: [{ name: 'Bella', age: 100 }],
  about: { height: '1.70', weight: '170' },
};
const ret = { ...existingObj, ...objToPush };
console.log(ret);
```